# How it's possible that DidResumeLocationUpdates is called by the system?

Tags: ios, core-location

In my log I can see that the system call `DidPauseLocationUpdates` and everything fine, for 30 min I didn't move and didn't receive any new location updates. then I decide to move and suddenly I see in the log an entry `DidResumeLocationUpdates` (but I didn't do anything for that) followed by new location updates

How it's possible? I was thinking that we must restart manually the `locationManager` after the system pause it automatically ?

from the doc of apple:

> You are responsible for restarting location services in your app. Core
>   Location does not resume updates automatically after it pauses them.

it's look like the documentation is false !

Comment: Are you sure that you are not subscribed for background service in background?

Comment: yes i m suscriber for background services, but what this change ? normally only me can resume the location update reading the doc, background or not! but it's true that putting the app in foreground imediatly call DidResumeLocationUpdates, don't know why

Comment: are you starting `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` ? If so, then your app will restart updating location once it detects a significant location change

Comment: yes but (like you suggest in previous post) on another CLLocationManager, also i didn't receive any locationManagerDidUpdateLocations before the seeing DidResumeLocationUpdates